# Get tick labels for matplotlib in semilogx plot that I can overwrite

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the following Matplotlib graph, I would like to:

1. Show the correct labels for all minor ticks
2. Be able to rename the major and minor ticks to the values I need

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ONE_YEAR_IN_DAYS = 365

ONE_DAY_IN_TIMESTAMP_UNITS = 86400000000000

import pandas as pd

start = pd.Timestamp('2016-07-01')
end = pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01')

t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 100 * ONE_YEAR_IN_DAYS)

sinus = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1 * t / ONE_DAY_IN_TIMESTAMP_UNITS)

t = end.value - t

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
font = {'family': 'normal',
        'size': 8}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axes = plt.gca()
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 400
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid()
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter
plt.minorticks_on()
formatter = LogFormatter(labelOnlyBase=True, )
plt.setp(axes.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=90)

locmaj = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=5.0,numticks=12)
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(locmaj)
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=5.0,subs=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),numticks=12)
axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
axes.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())

plt.semilogx(t, sinus, "-o", markersize=2)

plt.show()
```

I use Matplotlib 2.0.2.

As you can see, I struggle somehow with the correct minor label  generation.

This is the present result I get:

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. What is "the correct minor label generation", given that you remove all minor ticklabels in your code? How would you like the plot to look like?

Comment: Do you really want to show the minor tick labels on a logarithmic scale?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: in the first step I would like to see the minor ticklabels. In the second step I want to reformat/recalculate them manually to a formated datetime value.
@Bazingaa: yes, exactly. The background for my question is: I want to get a feeling whether with some "real" data, I can see enough details of older values (so e.g.: `1*10e13` is equivalent to half a day, `1*10e14` is equivalent to one day away from `now`etc.). `Now` is at the very left of the chart, `one year ago` is on the very right of the chart. Very recent data should be visible with more details.

Comment: I think you want to use a `FuncFormatter`, i.e. `set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(func))`, with `func` being a function that takes the location as input and outputs a string to be used as label.

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. I hope it is ok to post the next topic coming up in a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910194/how-to-rotate-axis-labels-for-minor-ticks-within-a-semilogx-plot)